# Can not mount samba share from DD-WRT

Tags: mount, samba, dd-wrt

I'm trying to mount a samba share on dd-wrt. I keep getting this in the dmesg and the mount command hangs.

```
CIFS VFS: Error connecting to IPv4 socket. Aborting operation
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -145
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
CIFS VFS: Error connecting to IPv4 socket. Aborting operation
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -145
CIFS VFS: Error connecting to IPv4 socket. Aborting operation
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -512
CIFS VFS: Error connecting to IPv4 socket. Aborting operation
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -512
CIFS VFS: Error connecting to IPv4 socket. Aborting operation
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -512
```

It doesn't appear that there is any documentation about these error codes out there so i have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

My command format is.

```
mount.cifs //10.0.10.145/<share> /opt/usr/server -o guest -v
```

On DD-WRT's site it say you can use smbmount but that doesn't appear to be a valid utility.